# convert from IIS rewrite to nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, iis

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="wfq2020">
                <match url="^(auth|platform-admin|product|substation-admin)/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://google.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    <rule name="api.wfq2020">
        <match url="^(wuneng-platform-web|wuneng-channel-web|wuneng-web|wuneng-user-web|mini-program)/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://api.google.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Here is my iis rule, I want to convert it to nginx rule, hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with IIS rewrite, but I have checked [their doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) and it seems pretty close to NGINX.

On NGINX, is recommended to use `return` if possible ([doc here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)). The `{R:0}` is similar to the [NGINX vars](https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html), in this case, the [`$request_uri`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri).

You can also combine with the `~*`, this is a "Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching)" ([doc here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)). The `^/...` means that it needs to start with it (e.g. starts with `/wuneng-platform-web` and anything else after that `(.*)`.

The code will be something like:

```
http {
  ## ...

  server {
    ## ...

    location ~* ^/(auth|platform-admin|product|substation-admin)(.*) {
        return 301 https://google.com$request_uri;
    }

    location ~* ^/(wuneng-platform-web|wuneng-channel-web|wuneng-web|wuneng-user-web|mini-program)(.*) {
        return 301 https://api.google.com$request_uri;
    }

    ## ...
  }

  ## ...

}
```

I hope this will help you out :)